# remove index.html from URL react app on S3 and CloudFront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting multiple react apps on one s3 bucket, that is connected to a CloudFront distro.
The react apps are placed in folders so for example the calculating app is located in /calculate in the S3 bucket.
I fixed issues that happened because react wasn't using paths in a relative way to the index.html (I added "homepage":"./" to the package.json). But I am struggling to remove the index.html from the URL for the end user.
Basically I want the index.html to appear when going on https://{domain}/calculate/ not https://{domain}/calculate/index.html . Does someone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a file just called ".htaccess" in the root directory and add the following to it:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove .html (or htm) from visible URL (permanent redirect)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.html?$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# Quietly point back to the HTML file (temporary/undefined redirect):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

Comment: Do you mean the root of the specific react application in the folder, or in the root of the s3 bucket? :) Thanks for you reply by the way @brandon-bronkhorst

Comment: No problem mate. For me personally adding it to the full root worked, not the root of the specific application. So adding it to the full root should resolve the issue through all the apps.

Comment: S3 is a content server and not a web server, so .htaccess won't have any effect